# Trying to take user input as loop counter [NASM Assembly language]

Tags: assembly, nasm

Im trying to run a loop that runs on a user entered value.

The data segment:

```
  BITS 32
 section .data                          
        msg db 'Enter the number of lines '
        len equ $-msg
        hello db 'Hello World ! '
        lenhello equ $-hello
        cr db 10
```

The .bss segment

```
section .bss    
        num resb 5
```

The .txt segment

```
section .text          ;Code Segment
       global _start

_start:                ;User prompt
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, msg
       mov edx, len
       int 80h

       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 2
       mov ecx, num
       mov edx, 5
       int 80h

       mov ecx, num ; i think the issue is here
li: 
       call newline
       push ecx
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1 
       mov ecx, hello
       mov edx, lenhello
       int 80h
       pop ecx
loop li
       mov eax, 1
       mov ebx, 0
       int 0x80
```

newline changes the line

```
 newline:          ; this changes the line
       push ecx
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, cr
       mov edx, 1
       int 0x80
       pop ecx
       ret
```

The code works perfectly when i replace num with a constant

```
mov ecx,5
```

I think its something to do with the datatype of num .

Comment: What happens when you run this under the debugger?  What value ends up in ecx?  At a guess, you're reading the string "5" from num instead of the numeric value 0x5.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: even worse, `mov ecx, num` in NASM puts the label address into ECX, `mov`-immediate not a load (like it would be in some other assemblers, e.g. GNU `.intel_syntax`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NASM an instruction like `mov ecx, num` loads the address of *num* in the register. To get what is stored at the address pointed to by *num*, you need to use the square brackets like in `mov ecx, [num]`.

The input that you got is text, but your loop needs an actual number for its loop counter. You need to do the conversion.

Assuming your input consisted of a single digit number, this is a good solution:

```
       movzx ecx, byte [num]  ; Fetch the single digit input from the buffer
       sub   cl, '0'          ; Conversion "0".."9" -> 0..9
       jz    Done             ; No lines requested
li: 
       call  newline
       push  ecx
       mov   eax, 4
       mov   ebx, 1 
       mov   ecx, hello
       mov   edx, lenhello
       int   80h
       pop   ecx
       dec   ecx
       jnz   li
Done:
```